# conditionally checking a value in PloneFormGen

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I have an information request form that has a series of checkboxes that i want to conditionally test and if checked I want to add content to the page.

The issue I'm having is that I can't find the the proper syntax to add to the template to make this happen:

curently i have:

```
<tal:block condition="python:request.form.get('my-field-name')">
content
</tal:block>
```

but I get no output, and I know there must be an easy way to get this done but I can't find any documentation dealing with this type of request. if someone could point me in the right direction that'd be of much help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it could be written more simply with path notation, there's nothing wrong with this. So, your problem is probably elsewhere.

Simpler:

```
<tal:block tal:condition="exists:request/form/my-field-name">
content
</tal:block>
```

Comment: yeah you where right it did lie elsewhere. your path notation is simpler thanks for the tip!